# How to handle multiple dependent asynchronous queries in Firestore

Tags: javascript, firebase, asynchronous, google-cloud-firestore, promise

I want to build a Q&A app with Firebase as backend.There are three collections in Firestore: `questions`,`answers` and `repliesToAnswers`. Documents in `question` have one field `content`, documents in `answers` have 2 fields `answerid` and `content`, documents in `repliesToAnswers` have 3 fields `answerId`,`questionId`and `content`.

```
questions: {
    content
}


answers: {
    questionId
    content 

}

repliesToAnswers {
    content
    answerId
    questionId 
}
```

My goal is to build a Restful API endpoint `/question/:questionId` that gets structured data like this

```
{
    "content": "How to ...",
    "answers": [
        {
            "content":"...",
            "replies": [
                {
                    "content":"..."
                },
                {
                    "content":"..."
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "content":"...",
            "replies":[]
        }
    ],
}
```

So I tried to write nested Promises that easily go wrong.

```js
exports.getQuestion = (request, response) => {
  console.log(request.params);

  let questionId = request.params.questionId;
  let question = {};

  firebase
  .firestore()
  .collection('questions')
  .doc(questionId)
  .get()
  .then(doc => {
    if(!doc.exists) {
      throw Error("doc not exists")
    }

    return doc;
  })
  .then(doc => {
    question.username = doc.data().username
    return doc.id 
  })
  .then(id => {
    // retrive answsers 
    let answers = [];

    firebase.firestore()
    .collection('answers')
    .where('questionId', '==', id)
    .get()
    .then(snapshot => {
      if (snapshot.empty) {
        console.log('no answers');
        return answers;
      }
      

      snapshot.forEach(ans => {
        // retrive replies
       
        let replies = [];
        
        firebase.firestore()
          .collection('repliesToAnswers')
          .where('questionId','==',questionId)
          .where('answerId','==', ans.id)
          .get()
          .then(snapshot => {
            if(snapshot.empty) {
              console.log(`no reply to answer(id:${ans.id}) of question(${questionId})`);
              return [];
            }


            snapshot.forEach(reply => {
              console.log(reply.id);
              replies.push({
                content: reply.data().content
              })

            })

            return replies; 

           
          })

        answers.push({
          content: ans.data().content,
          replies: replies
        })
      
      });
      return answers;
    })
    .then(answers => {
      question.answers = answers;
      return response.json(question);
    })

  })
  .catch(error => {
    console.log(error);
    response.status(500).json({
      error: error.code
    })
  })
  
};
```

The problem is that the function returned empty reply arrays for each answers. It skipped the request retrieving replies for each answer. Can anyone helps me out? Or are there better styles to achieve it?

**-----Update-----**

To make the easier to read I use `Promise.all()` that remains the same logic

```js
exports.getQuestion = (request, response) => {


  let questionId = request.params.questionId;
  let question = {};
  let answers = [];
  
  // retrive attribute content for Object question
  let fetchQuestion = firebase.firestore()
                      .doc(`questions/${questionId}`)
                      .get()
                      .then(doc => {
                        if(!doc.exists) {
                          throw Error('doc not exists')
                        }
                        return doc 
                      })
                      .then(doc => {
                        question.content = doc.data().content
                      })
                      .catch(error => {
                        console.log(error)
                      });
  // push result to answers
  let fetchAnswers = firebase.firestore()
                      .collection('answers')
                      .where('questionId','==',questionId)
                      .get()
                      .then(snapshot => {
                        if(snapshot.empty) {
                          console.log('no replies'); 
                          return;
                        } else {
                          snapshot.forEach(ans => {
                            answers.push({
                              content: ans.data().content, 
                              replies: [], 
                              id: ans.id 
                            })
                          })
                        }
                      }).catch(error => {
                        console.log(error); 
                      });
  let fetchAnsReplies = fetchAnswers.then(() => {
    answers.forEach(ans => {
      firebase.firestore() 
      .collection('repliesToAnswers')
      .where('answerId','==',ans.id)
      .get()
      .then(snapshot => {
        if(snapshot.empty) {

          console.log('no reply');
          return;
        } else {

          
          
          snapshot.forEach(reply => {
             ans.replies.push({
               content: reply.data()
             })
           })
        } 
      }).catch(error => {
        console.log(error); 
      })
    })

  }).catch(error => {
    console.log(error);
  })

  return Promise.all([fetchQuestion,fetchAnswers, fetchAnsReplies])
  .then(() => {
    return response.json({...question, answers: answers})
  }).catch(error => {
    console.log(error);
    response.status(500).json({
      error: error.code
    })

  })

}
```

Comment: You use the `replies` arrays before you *asynchronously* `push` values into it. You need to wait for the promises inside the snapshot loops as well.

Comment: Code would be easier to read if the queries were pulled out as functions, eg `getQuestion()`, `getAnswers()`, `getReplies()`, each comprising `return firebase.firestore().method(...).method(...).get()`. Apart from that, the overall approach is essentially sound. Just needs fixing as indicated by @Bergi.

Comment: It should be possible to pass data down the promise chain and compose `question` in a final `.then()` thus avoiding the need for the rather ugly outer `let question = {}`.

Comment: @Roamer-1888 Thanks, I finally resolve it by `Promise.all()`

Comment: @Bergi Thanks, it get it resolved by `Promise.all()` with codes much more elegant

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally get it resolved by `Promise.all()` with codes much more elegant.

```js
exports.getQuestion = (request, response) => {


  let questionId = request.params.questionId;
 // let question = {};
  //let answers = [];

  // get info except answers 
  // { content:XXX, answers: []  }
  let fetchQuestion = firebase.firestore()
                      .doc(`questions/${questionId}`)
                      .get()
                      .then(doc => {
                        if(!doc.exists) {
                          throw Error('doc not exists');
                        }
                        return doc 
                      })
                      .then(doc => {
                        return {
                          content: doc.data().content,
                          id: doc.id,
                          answers: []
                        }
                      })
                      .catch(error => {
                        console.log(error)
                      });

  // return answers 
  let fetchAnswers =  firebase.firestore()
                      .collection('answers')
                      .where('questionId','==',questionId)
                      .get()
                      .then(snapshot => {
                        if(snapshot.empty) {
                          console.log('no replies'); 
                          return [];
                        } else {
                          let answers = []; 
                          snapshot.forEach(ans => {
                            // add answers to question
                            answers.push({
                              content: ans.data().content, 
                              replies: [], 
                              id: ans.id 
                            })

                          })

                          return answers;
                        }
                      }).catch(error => {
                        console.log(error); 
                      });

  

  let fetchAnsReplies = fetchAnswers.then(answers => {
    var promises = []; 
   
    answers.forEach(ans => {
      var promise = firebase.firestore() 
      .collection('repliesToAnswers')
      .where('answerId','==',ans.id)
      .get()
      .then(snapshot => {
        if(snapshot.empty) {

          console.log('no reply');
          return;
        } else {
          
          snapshot.forEach(reply => {
         
            ans.replies.push({
              content: reply.data()
            })
          })
        } 
      }).catch(error => {
        console.log(error); 
      })

      promises.push(promise);
    })


    return Promise.all(promises).then(() => {
      
      return answers;
    })

  }).catch(error => {
    console.log(error);
  })

  return Promise.all([fetchQuestion,fetchAnswers, fetchAnsReplies])
  .then(results => {
    return response.json({...results[0],answers:results[2]});
  }).catch(error => {
    console.log(error);
    response.status(500).json({
      error: error.code
    })

  })

}
```